# how can i combine and store 2 char variables in an integer variable?

Tags: c, memory-management, bitwise-operators, type-conversion

consider the following data:

```
char a=12,b=30;
int c=0;
```

i want the variable c to store the combined value as c=1230.
i.e the int datatype  has 2bytes,the first byte should hold value of a and the second the value of b. 
PS: a soln using operators would be great,any other suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 4):

You can use bitwise operations as an alternative. A char is guaranteed to be 1 byte, so you can store it by shifting one char then use the operation OR to combine them:

```
int combine(char c1, char c2) {
    return c1 | c2 << 8;
}
```

Then you can use AND and a right shift to split them again:

```
void split(int in, char *c1, char *c2) {
    *c1 = in & 0xff;
    *c2 = in >> 8;
}
```

This will, however, not give you the output you want but it will store two chars within one int.

Comment: s/0b11111111/0xff/ ?

Comment: @BjornA. That does look way neater. I should probably look into hexadecimal, aha. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1230 = 12*100 + 30.  So it seems you could assign `a*100+b` to `c`.

But if either `a` or `b` is not in the range 0..99 (inclusive), that might not work the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a union like this

```
typedef union {
        char bytes[2];
        int integer;
} combined;
```

and then store the chars like

```
char a = 12;
char b = 30;

combined c;
c.bytes[0] = a;
c.bytes[1] = b;
```

and c.integer will now store both of the chars. Please note though, that since an `int` is often 32 bits wide, 16 of the bits will be "random", so you cannot compare two `int`s created this way. A better choice would be a `short`.

As in the other answers, this does not give you the output you want, but just a way to store two chars in an int.